# jQuery ScrollTo Next and Previous Element with Class Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you transverse up and down in this example?  This comes from a previous question, but I am unsure on how to transverse this when I add in a parent container div. If you remove the container div it all works, but I need to have the container.  Also, it will need to skip over divs that don't have the class post.  I am getting confused with possibly using parent(), next(), find(), etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/bs6443y4/148/

HTML:

```
    <nav>
      <a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
      <a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nisi veniam doloribus iste cumque sint facere consequuntur quas blanditiis nam consequatur molestias quo distinctio ab repellendus sequi saepe. Vel nisi.
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="post three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
var $currentElement = $(".post").first();
    $("#down").click(function() {
      var $nextElement = $currentElement.next('.post');
      if ($nextElement.length) {
        $currentElement = $nextElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
          scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }
      return false;
    });

    $("#up").click(function() {
      var $prevElement = $currentElement.prev('.post');
      if ($prevElement.length) {            
        $currentElement = $prevElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
          scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: This `var $currentElement = $(".post").first();` is getting the first element with class `.post` and assigning to `$currentElement` the first element iside it

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL How do you advance to the next div with class post?

Answer (score 0):

I see your update that you can't just change scrolling to use the `container`, because you only want to scroll to containers that have `post` elements.

You can still achieve this by using `container` (as it is the main container), we just need to change the selectors to also take the `post` into account. You can also scroll directly to the post element, its just a bit more complicated. Simple is always better so I'll explain scrolling to the container first!

**Option 1: Scroll to `container` elements that have a child with class `post`**

To do this, you just need to make 3 changes to your current code:

```
// 1. set currentElement to the first container (it doesn't matter if it has a post, it's just our starting point)
var $currentElement = $(".container").first(); 

$("#down").click(function() {
    //2. select the next container that has a post
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.nextAll(":has(.post):first");
    [...]
});

$("#up").click(function() {
    //3. select the previous container that has a post
    var $prevElement = $currentElement.prevAll(":has(.post):first");
    [...]
});
```

**What this does:**

- `nextAll()` / `prevAll()`: Get the all of the siblings following/preceding the current element...
- `:has(.post)`: that have a child with the `post` class...
- `:first`: and select the first one as our next element

**Working Example:**

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7juv0hw/ or a runnable snippet:

```js
var $currentElement = $(".container").first();
$("#down").click(function() {
  var $nextElement = $currentElement.nextAll(":has(.post):first");
  if ($nextElement.length) {
    $currentElement = $nextElement;
    $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
      scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
  return false;
});

$("#up").click(function() {
  var $prevElement = $currentElement.prevAll(":has(.post):first");
  if ($prevElement.length) {
    $currentElement = $prevElement;
    $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
      scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.container,
.post {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.one {
  background: orange;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
  <a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nisi veniam doloribus iste cumque sint facere consequuntur quas blanditiis nam consequatur molestias quo distinctio ab repellendus sequi saepe. Vel nisi.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Option 2: Scroll to `post` elements**

Because the post elements aren't direct siblings, this is a bit more complicated to achieve. You need to do the following:

```
// 1. set currentElement to the first post (this is what you already have, I've just included it as a comparison to option 1)
var $currentElement = $(".container").first(); 

$("#down").click(function() {
    //2. select the next sibling of the parent (container) that has a post
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.parent().nextAll(":has(.post):first").find(".post").first();
    [...]
});

$("#up").click(function() {
    //3. select the previous sibling of the parent that that has a post
    var $prevElement = $currentElement.parent().prevAll(":has(.post):first").find(".post").first();
    [...]
});
```

**What this does:**

- `parent()`: Get the parent of the current element (i.e. the container)...
- `nextAll()` / `prevAll()`: then get the all of the siblings following/preceding the current element...
- `:has(.post)`: that have a child with the `post` class...
- `:first`: then select the first one...
- `find(".post")`: and get all its children that have the `post` class
- `first()`: and select the first of these elements as the current element

**Working Example:**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7juv0hw/1/ or Snippet:

```js
var $currentElement = $(".post").first();
$("#down").click(function() {
  var $nextElement = $currentElement.parent().nextAll(":has(.post):first").find(".post").first();
  if ($nextElement.length) {
    $currentElement = $nextElement;
    $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
      scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
  return false;
});

$("#up").click(function() {
  var $prevElement = $currentElement.parent().prevAll(":has(.post):first").find(".post").first();
  if ($prevElement.length) {
    $currentElement = $prevElement;
    $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
      scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.container,
.post {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.one {
  background: orange;
}

.two {
  background: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" id="down">Down</a>
  <a href="#" id="up">Up</a>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post one">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nisi veniam doloribus iste cumque sint facere consequuntur quas blanditiis nam consequatur molestias quo distinctio ab repellendus sequi saepe. Vel nisi.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Skip me Because I am not a div with class post
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam rerum laboriosam at eum soluta itaque temporibus voluptatibus officia dicta amet quas vero ab eos magni molestiae. Debitis velit consectetur reiciendis.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry just added an update that there are container divs that do not contain a div with class post = skip over them.  I can scroll to the parent container div, but it has to have a div with a class of post.

Comment: @RooksStrife OK, I'm going to delete my answer because its wrong, and then I'll take a look at your new requirements

Comment: k thanks - sorry about that.  Didn't think about it until it was too late.

Comment: @RooksStrife I've taken a look at your updated question and updated my answer, let me know if this works for you or if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain your starting `.post` will exist in a container `DIV` this should work:

```
$("#down").click(function() {
  var $parentNext = $currentElement.parent().next();
  while ($parentNext.length > 0) {
    if ($parentNext.find('.post').length > 0) {
      $nextElement = $($parentNext.find('.post')[0]);
      $currentElement = $nextElement;
      $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
    $parentNext = $parentNext.next();
  }
  return false;
});

$("#up").click(function() {
  var $parentPrev = $currentElement.parent().prev();
  // Check if previous element actually exists
  while ($parentPrev.length > 0) {
    if ($parentPrev.find('.post').length > 0) {
      var $prevElement = $($parentPrev.find('.post')[0]);
      $currentElement = $prevElement;
      $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
    $parentPrev = $parentPrev.prev();
  }
  return false;
});
```